# How align Optionmenu using grid in centre of window in tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to align Optionmenu in center and side by side but whenever I uncomment the `.grid()` statements nothing is displayed in window it becomes blank.

```
import tkinter as tk
from utils import editionMap, topicMap, langMap

class OptionMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.status.set(status)

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, self.status, *options)
        self.dropdown.pack()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Edition_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Edition", *editionMap.keys())
    #Edition_Filter.grid(row=0, column=0)  <---Uncomment
    Language_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Language", *langMap.keys())
    #Language_Filter.grid(row=0, column=1) <---Uncomment
    Topic_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Topic", *topicMap.keys())
    #Topic_Filter.grid(row=0, column=2)    <---Uncomment

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want the display option menu as `Edition   Language   Topic` side by side horizontally.

My actual output is:

[image]

Comment: if you create `Frame` inside then you have to use arguments in `self.frame.pack()`. And you can't use `grid()` - or you use `self.frame.grid()` instead of `self.frame.pack()`

Comment: @furas I know that 'pack' and 'grid' should not be mixed can you edit above code in terms of grids only.

Comment: you mix two different technic `self.frame = tk.Frame(master)` and `class OptionMenu(tk.Frame):` - see again code in previous question.

Comment: @furas so I dont have to pass argument in class am I correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mix two different technics

First: inheriting

```
class OptionMenu(tk.Frame): # <-- with Frame

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        super().__init__(master) # <-- with super()
```

Second: including

```
class OptionMenu(): # <-- without Frame

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(master) # <-- create inner widget
```

First create real widget which can use `menu.pack()` or `menu.grid()`

Second doesn't create widget - it create normal class with widget inside and you have to use `menu.frame.pack()` or `menu.frame.grid()`

---

Example with real widget

```
import tkinter as tk

class OptionMenu(tk.Frame): # <-- with Frame

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):

        super().__init__(master) # <-- with super()

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.status.set(status)

        # use `self` as parent for widgets inside

        self.dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.status, *options)
        self.dropdown.pack()


def main():

    editionMap = {1:"English", 2:"German", 3:"Russian"}
    langMap = {1:"English", 2:"German", 3:"Russian"}
    topicMap = {1:"English", 2:"German", 3:"Russian"}

    root = tk.Tk()

    Edition_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Edition", *editionMap.keys())
    Edition_Filter.grid(row=0, column=0)

    Language_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Language", *langMap.keys())
    Language_Filter.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Topic_Filter = OptionMenu(root, "Topic", *topicMap.keys())
    Topic_Filter.grid(row=0, column=2)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `soon` means `"soon will be ready"` - but now it is ready, see answer again.

Comment: You are saviour. Salute to you man. I will ping you on stackoverflow if needed is it Ok.

Comment: OK, I'm on SO almost every day. If I will tired of SO then maybe I go back to Python groups o FB: [Python](https://www.facebook.com/groups/gpython/) and [Python Programming Language](https://www.facebook.com/groups/python.programmers/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787955/not-able-to-get-json-response-due-to-unicodedecodeerror can you tell me how to fix this.

Comment: how can I use above example code without `super()` and `grid()` as it is difficult to understand when to use `super()` and when not.

Comment: if you inherit from other class - ie. `class OptionMenu(tk.Frame)` - then you have to use `super().__init__()` to execute original `__init__()` - ie. `tk.Frame.__init__()` which does many important things.

Comment: Why pass `tk.Frame` in OptionMenu?

Comment: as for `grip()` - you can use `pack()` but (as for me) with `grip()` it can be easier. If you have to use `pack()` and `grid()` the you can `pack()`  frame and use `grid()` inside frame`

Comment: So basically use `pack()` on frame and inside frame use `grid()`

Comment: because originally I created new widget with two elements inside - `OptionMenu` and `Label` - so I used `Frame` to group them.

Comment: See what I want to do is without `super()` can I use `grid()` on objects created by `OptionMenu` class from `main()`

Comment: we use `Frame` to group elements for three reasons: 1. to use different layout manager inside and outside (you can have `pack()` outside and `grid()` inside, or `grid()` outside and `pack()` inside). 2. to create widget with many elements. 3. to easily show/hide many elements - you can elements in Frame and you have to hide only Frame instead of many separated elements.

Comment: if you create `MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):` then you HAVE TO use `super().__init__()` or `OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)` inside `__init__()`. If you don't use it then it will not work correctly.

Comment: your `def __init__(self, master, status, *options):` replaced oryginal `OptionMenu.__init__()` so you have to call it manually inside your `def __init__()`

Comment: you can use `pack()` or `grid()` or `place()` on class with `super()` in `__init__()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811739/how-to-use-class-methods-from-another-py-file-both-files-in-same-package-and-wh?noredirect=1#comment82585830_47811739