# Not able to get JSON response due to UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to get JSON response when I try to run `python core-backup.py` file: In code FB_SHORT_ACCESS_TOKEN and FB_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN are same.

core-backup.py :

```
import os
from os.path import join
import requests


def refresh_short_token():
    """
    Refresh short access token
    """
    request_url = FB_URL + 'oauth/access_token'
    request_payload = {
        'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
        'client_id': FB_APP_ID,
        'client_secret': FB_APP_SECRET,
        'fb_exchange_token': FB_SHORT_ACCESS_TOKEN
    }
    response = REQ_SESSION.get(request_url, params=request_payload).json()
    # dotenvfile = find_dotenv()
    # load_dotenv(dotenvfile)
    # dotenv.set_key(dotenvfile, "FB_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN", response['access_token'])
    FB_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN = response["access_token"]
    # PAYLOAD['access_token'] = dotenv.get_key(dotenvfile, "FB_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN")
    PAYLOAD['access_token'] = FB_LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN

'''
TODO: refresh_long_token()
    A function to refresh the long term access token
    Current validity: 60 days
'''

def get_feed():
    """
    Fetch feed
    """
    request_url = FB_URL + LTTK_GROUP_ID + '/feed'
    response = REQ_SESSION.get(request_url, params=PAYLOAD)
    if response.status_code == 400:
        refresh_short_token()
    print(response.json())
    return response.json()

def main():
    """
    Fetch posts from a Facebook group and populate in database
    """
    get_feed()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting UnicodeDecodeError in windows7 after running core-backup.py
file. How to fix this issue.
See screenshot for more clarity:

[image]

Entire code of file can be found out here: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ab9e023d631a7cc4dad15237104ee34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code page is set to cp437. Try setting python output to utf-8 by entering the following line in your terminal before running your python script.

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
python core-backup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing response encoding to `UTF-8`:

```
response.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print(response.json())
```