# How to use class methods from another .py file both files in same package and when both are in different folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Case1: Following is the file structure all are in same folder:

```
`Folder1
    |__init__.py
    |gnewsclient.py
    |test.py
    |utils.py`

1)Content of 
__init__.py

`from .gnewsclient import gnewsclient`

2) Content of client.py

`class gnewsclient:
      //Some methods
`

3)Content of `utils.py`

Some Dictionaries inside utils.py

4)Content of `test.py`:
    Here I want to import methods from client.py which has gnewsclient class()


Now I want to import methods from gnewsclient class of `client.py` file inside test.py

All are in same folder above

In `test.py`:

I tried  

`from client import *` 

or

`from .client import gnewsclient`
```

but it says parent module not loaded '' cannot perform relative import.

Case2: Also now if I make a folder2 which has test.py inside it and try to do same importing still it gives no parent module cannot perform relative import.

Comment: if they are in the same directory there is no use of init.py , you can simply have three files except init.py and then if you want to import gnewsclient in current module then simply use from . import gnewsclient, and then in next line specify the name of the method in the gnewsclient , like gnewsclient.method

Comment: @babygame0ver Did you checked folder1 init.py file I do not want to change anything inside it can you please tell me any solution.

Comment: In your test.py type this on the top from gnewsclient import class_name, but the method of the class will be called only by the object of the class , so make a object of the imported class in test.py ,

Comment: @babygame0ver Does not work it says cannot do relative import

Comment: wait I will post the example in the answer

Comment: is it working for you bro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Content of gnewsclient.py**

```
class baby():
    def method(self):
        print 'Method call'
```

**Content of test.py**

```
from gnewsclient import baby # from file_name.py import class_name

b = baby()
b.method()
```

> > python test.py

**Output**

**Method call**